# Magento2 - Save & Duplicate is not work

Tags: magento2, duplicate

When I click **'Save & Duplicate'** button, **'Please wait...'** show up and it can't finish. Just show 'Please wait...' endless

What should I check?

No 3rd party module, Fresh installed Magento2 with sample products

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Magento-2 duplicate product will not created from admin because of there is a magento-2 default version bug.

Still bug is open on github, You can check it from here : [Product Duplication crash](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4096)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it happens when you get an exception on the server side.
First of all, you should check var/log/exception.log of your Magento 2 installation. If you see many records there and not sure they are related to your issue - try to reproduce the issue once again and check the record timestamp in the log (the recent records are in the end of the log file). If still nothing, it's a good idea to check the apache/nginx error logs. The issue might be there.
You can check the issue in the interactive mode as well if you are able to set store to the developer mode. Execute the following command in your shell (from the Magento installation root directory):

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

After the mode is changed, clean the cache, open the product edit page once again, open your browser (Google Chrome) developer console (Network tab) and hit "Save & Duplicate" once again. In the developer console network tab you should see one or few new requests. The failed one should be highlighted by red color. Click on this request and check it's response. In the developer mode the response has a detailed error trace.
Good luck.